# find next prime number in array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, primes

I had an interview question yesterday and it's been bugging me trying to figure out how to get the next prime number in the number line of an array.

```
function isPrime(num) {
    for (var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(num) + 1; ++i) {
        if (num % i === 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return num !== 1;
}

function getNextPrime(prime) {
      for (var count = prime + 1; ; ++count) {
        if (isPrime(count)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return count;
}



console.log(getNextPrime([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(getNextPrime([2, 7, 11, 13]));
console.log(getNextPrime([19, 2, 13, 4]));
console.log(getNextPrime([2, 4, 6, 8]));
```

Comment: Next to what -- the last element of the array?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with `prime + 1`?

Comment: Was it all the data they gave you on the interview ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//if prime next to last element of array?

    function isPrime(num) {
        for (var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(num) + 1; ++i) {
            if (num % i === 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return num !== 1;
    }

    function getNextPrime(prime) {
  var sortedArray = prime.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
     var last = sortedArray[sortedArray.length-1];
        for (var count = last + 1; ; ++count) {
           if (isPrime(count)) {
               break;
           }
        }
        return count;
    }

    console.log(getNextPrime([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
    console.log(getNextPrime([2, 7, 11, 13]));
    console.log(getNextPrime([19, 2, 13, 4]));
```

Comment: Why assume it's from the last element? What if the array was `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` and you returned `3` but they don't want duplicates so the answer should return `7`?

Comment: I should have clarified, they want the next number pushed into an array.

Comment: console.log(getNextPrime([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])); => [1, 3, 5, 4, 7];  // non-prime numbers stay in the array
    console.log(getNextPrime([2, 7, 11, 13])); => [3, 11, 13, 17]
    console.log(getNextPrime([19, 2, 13, 4])); => [23, 3, 17, 4] // non-prime numbers stay in the array

Answer (score 0):

```js
const isPrime = function(n){
  if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<2) {
   return false;
  }

  if (n%2==0){
   return (n==2);
  }

  var sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);
  for (var i = 3; i < sqrt; i+=2) {
   if(n%i == 0){
    return false;
   }
  }

  return true;
 }

const getNextPrime = function* (){
  let nextNumber = 2;
  while(true){
   if(isPrime(nextNumber)){
    yield nextNumber;
   }
   ++nextNumber;
  }
 }
  
  const nextNumner = getNextPrime();
  console.log(nextNumner.next().value);
```

every time we call nextNumner.next().value we get the next prime value.